# After catching exception ,the emulator still shows "Application has stopped unexpectedly "

Tags: java, android, exception, android-emulator, try-catch

```
private InputStream getISFromURL(String url) {
  //post
  InputStream is=null;
  try {
    HttpParams params=new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 3000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 3000);
    HttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient(params);
    HttpPost httpPost=new HttpPost(url);
    HttpResponse httpResponce=httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity httpEntity=httpResponce.getEntity();
    is=httpEntity.getContent();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    this.context.startActivity(new Intent(this.context, Splash.class));
    Log.d("imsoft", "getJSONdataFromURL ="+e.toString());
  }
  return is;
}
```

This code works good if the internet connection is alive but when i disconnect my system(which disconnects emulator too) then this method throws UnknownHostException and it is catched in the catch block by opening my Splash.java(splash screen) but at the same time it also give me *"Application has stopped unexpectedly Please try again" .*

So please give me answer or suggestions that can help me.

Comment: Maybe it's just after (you return null in the case of an Exception, maybe this cause a NullPointerException afterwards). try to type `adb logcat` in a  shell to see what happens and where it happens.

Comment: Thank you ,sir your this point that "it will return null in the case of an exception" helped me a lot.It was really returning a null input stream which cause this error.Once again thank you very much.Sir you have not answered it that I can accept your answer.Please answer it in a useful way it will help others too.

Comment: reposted my comment as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As asked by you, here's my comment in a more formal answer:

Maybe your problem is caused by the fact that you you return null in the case of an Exception.

The caller might throw a NullPointerException if it fails to check that your method result is not null before referencing it.

Try type `adb logcat` in a shell to see what happens and where it happens.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is throwing exception because after catch block it is coming to this statement `return is;` which is think null if code throw exception.

Comment: Thanks a lot ,sir your point is same as Laurent' said.I have commented him if he dose not answered I will accept your answer.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```
public static boolean isOnline(Context mContext) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

to control if you're online or not. You have to add permission to do this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: I have tried it but it returns always true in my case as I am checking on emulator.I dont know if it works on real android device.thanks